# Add custom tab to facebook page using different urls

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-tabs

hi to all and tx for your support.

until now to add a custom tab to facebook page i use this url
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=APP-ID&redirect_uri=APP-URL

in this way i add correctly the Secure Page Tab URL to my facebook page.

my problem is that i need to add different tabs related to different urls inside the same application. i need to add for example a tab called "CONTACT" related to APP-URL/contact, another tab called "PRODUCTS" related to APP-URL/products and so on. i don't want create more than one facebook application to do this, is it possibile?

Answer (score 2):

That is impossible, you can´t install an App more than one time per Page. You can only show different content depending on the Page by reading the Page ID in the [signed_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gamesonfacebook/login#usingsignedrequest) parameter.

In other words: One App can be installed on several Pages, but one App can only be installed one time per Page.

Information about how to use the signed_request parameter can be found in many Stackoverflow threads, for example: [how to read facebook signed_request to get user_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973251/how-to-read-facebook-signed-request-to-get-user-id)

It´s a simple POST parameter and you need to parse it. Just debug the result and you will see the Page ID.