# dynamic secure page tab url in facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-page

I want to use dynamic URL for Facebook page tab for that purpose i want to need secure page tab URL different for every user how can i do this can any body help me?
[image]

Comment: How exactly is this related to programming?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic URLs per Page are impossible, it´s just one setting. You can get the Page ID though: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_access_token_from_page_tab/ (see `$helper->getSignedRequest()`)

Fields in `signed_request`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request

More information: [how to read facebook signed_request to get user_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973251/how-to-read-facebook-signed-request-to-get-user-id)